# Crop many pictures as circle in Android

Tags: android, custom-component, android-listfragment, navigation-drawer

Got a problem and I cannot solve it : I'd like to crop as circle many pictures coming from a ListFragment. It will be more explicit with the code :

```
String[] countries = new String[] {
    "Amel Mahmuzić",
    "Laurent Meyer",
    "Philipp Bellé",
    "Dennis Pagano",
    "Bill Gates",
    "Steve Jobs",
    "Jean Bonnot",
    "Nicolas Sarkozy",
    "Bob Marley",
    "Thomas Pieronczyk"
};

int[] flags = new int[]{
    R.drawable.amel_mahmuzic,
    R.drawable.laurent,
    R.drawable.phillip_belle,
    R.drawable.dennis_pagano,
    R.drawable.bill_gates,
    R.drawable.steve_jobs,
    R.drawable.jean_bonnot,
    R.drawable.nicolas_sarkozy,
    R.drawable.bob_marley,
    R.drawable.thomas_pieronczyk,
};

String[] currency = new String[]{
    "MoID GmbH",
    "MoID GmbH",
    "MoID GmbH",
    "MoID GmbH",
    "Microsoft",
    "Apple",
    "Pôle Emploi",
    "Elysée",
    "Weed Fabric",
    "MoID GmbH"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur", currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.image_item, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Ok, I know what you''l say :"it's not flag, not currency..." Example coming from the Internet and working. I just want to know how I can crop my picture as a circle.

And if nobody finds, does somebody know how to do an overlay with a square and a transparent circle whose color change when clicking ?

If you'd like to see what it looks like :

[image: What it currently lokks like]

Comment: Where is the code you've come up with to try this? All I see is you filling an adapter. Have you tried to implement anything, or are you just asking for the whole thing in a tidy package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could combine the answers given in the following two posts:

Create a bitmap:
[How to crop an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android)

Crop the bitmap to a circle using canvas.
[Android - Cut a circle from a square Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285661/android-cut-a-circle-from-a-square-bitmap)

Kind regards