# Circled camera preview in android

Tags: android, background, android-camera, rounding

I need to build an app that required a circular camera.
I know there's a way to do that by setting the backgroung rounded but i want to make the camera itself round.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about what you're trying todo? Do you want a round preview view or are you trying to make some kind of fisheye mapping?

Comment: I need to capture a ball and only the ball without any of the ball's background @makadev

Comment: Technically thats not possible. The camera will give you some hardware supported format like 480x640. There are ways to modify the captured data afterwards thought. Maybe [this entry about preview manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview) and [this entry about drawing a bitmap circular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285661/android-cut-a-circle-from-a-square-bitmap) helps a bit. It's quite dusty tho.